# Display a count of a cycle

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, cycle

I have three variables, one is called A = 2012, the second is called B = 2020 and the third is C = B - A. C is the difference of years. Now I would like to see on the screen the years between two dates:
2012
2013
2014
2015
2016
2017
2018
2019
2020.
I tried different solutions, but I can not do it, I think that the right approach is a cycle. Is it right? Could you show me how to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Please include your code and someone will help you from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean loop with cycle?
You could try this:

```
int a = 2012;             // Holds the first year
int b = 2020;             // Holds the last year
int c = b - a;            // Holds the difference of the a and b
while(a<=b) {             // Execute this as long as a is equal or less then b
    NSLog("Year: %d", a); // Print the year to the console
    a++;                  // Increment the value of a with 1
}
```

Comment: This solution works better because in the meantime I added an if else statment. Thanks to all.

Comment: If this is a homework assignment and you were told to use all 3 variables please note that `c` is not used in this example and most modern compilers will complain.

Answer (score -2):

```
for(int i=0;i<=c;i++)
{
 NSLog(@"The Year is %i \n",a+i);
}
```

Comment: nice try... but where is "C" in the equation?

Comment: Really? 2 down votes for not using the letter c... I'm just not up voting because this is only a solution without an explanation, and the OP seems very new to programming, and this may be a homework assignment.

Comment: Thanks, I tried and it works wonders, but it returns an issue that tells me that the variable "i" is not used, there is a way to solve this thing? However, the answer has already been accepted.

Comment: @Joe I downvoted because the dubbeat's original answer wasn't useful at all.

Comment: the original answer was "i=a" and "a<=b". The exact same result. In one way c is not used. in the other way b is not used.